# AlreadyExistsError: File system for s3 already registered

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running this on Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.9.12 and TensorFlow 2.6.0

**Specs:**

- Windows 10
- Python: 3.9.12
- TF: 2.6.0
- Keras: 2.6.0
- IPython: 7.18.1

I resolved another AlreadyExistsError, which was Keras not being the same version as TensorFlow. But for this, I couldn't find an answer in particular.
Here are the simple import statements:

```
#import os
from object_detection.utils import label_map _util
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
#from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
```

Here's the description of the error. What have I been doing wrong? How can I fix this?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AlreadyExistsError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-23c38f3704f8> in <module>
      1 #import os
      2 from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
----> 3 from object_detection.builders import model_builder
      4 #from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

~\github clones boi\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py in <module>
     35 from object_detection.meta_architectures import center_net_meta_arch
     36 from object_detection.meta_architectures import context_rcnn_meta_arch
---> 37 from object_detection.meta_architectures import deepmac_meta_arch
     38 from object_detection.meta_architectures import faster_rcnn_meta_arch
     39 from object_detection.meta_architectures import rfcn_meta_arch

~\github clones boi\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\deepmac_meta_arch.py in <module>
     26 
     27 if tf_version.is_tf2():
---> 28   import tensorflow_io as tfio  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
     29 
     30 

~\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\__init__.py in <module>
     15 """tensorflow_io"""
     16 
---> 17 from tensorflow_io.python.api import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
     18 from tensorflow_io.python.api.version import VERSION as __version__

~\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\python\api\__init__.py in <module>
     17 
     18 # tensorflow_io.core.python.ops is implicitly imported (along with file system)
---> 19 from tensorflow_io.python.ops.io_dataset import IODataset
     20 from tensorflow_io.python.ops.io_tensor import IOTensor
     21 

~\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\python\ops\__init__.py in <module>
     94 core_ops = LazyLoader("core_ops", "libtensorflow_io.so")
     95 try:
---> 96     plugin_ops = _load_library("libtensorflow_io_plugins.so", "fs")
     97 except NotImplementedError as e:
     98     warnings.warn(f"unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: {e}")

~\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\python\ops\__init__.py in _load_library(filename, lib)
     62     for f in filenames:
     63         try:
---> 64             l = load_fn(f)
     65             if l is not None:
     66                 return l

~\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\python\ops\__init__.py in <lambda>(f)
     54         load_fn = lambda f: ctypes.CDLL(f, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
     55     elif lib == "fs":
---> 56         load_fn = lambda f: tf.experimental.register_filesystem_plugin(f) is None
     57     else:
     58         load_fn = lambda f: tf.compat.v1.load_file_system_library(f) is None

~\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py in register_filesystem_plugin(plugin_location)
    216   """
    217   if os.path.exists(plugin_location):
--> 218     py_tf.TF_RegisterFilesystemPlugin(plugin_location)
    219 
    220   else:

AlreadyExistsError: File system for s3 already registered
```

Thanks in advance!